# Select records from a table which date will be 3 months from now

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a `products` table which contains `expiry_date (VARCHAR)`. How to select products which would be expiring 3 months from now to be displayed on a table with PHP?

EDIT: expiry_date format is 2017-01-01 (Y-m-d)

Comment: `expiry_date (VARCHAR)` that's a bad idea. You should use mysql's built-in date / time functions

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm new to SQL thanks for the advice!

Comment: you're welcome. It's better in many ways since using varchar makes it all that much harder to query and you have to resort to other functions. If the external data is coming from elsewhere being in another format, it's easier to transform it before it goes in db, from `d-m-Y` to `YYYY-mm-dd` as mysql prefers.

Comment: It's not too late to not use varchar if you're not too far into your project, but `DATE` or `DATETIME`. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 3):

Better option is to use date and time functions in mysql instead of making varchar for date stuffs.

You can use `DATE_ADD` and `BETWEEN`.

Use `STR_TO_DATE` to convert date to varchar

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl
WHERE  STR_TO_DATE(varchar_expiry_date, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN now() 
                   AND DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
```